# Await - Async does not make function synchronous in behaviour

Tags: node.js, async-await, node-request

I am trying to run the following function which performs request.get to an array of URL's, and then write to an array, the whole operation needs to be synchronous. But my code is not synchronous, and prints different output each time:

```
var arrayPart = [];

fileDecode : async function(fileName,filePath){
    for (a=0; a< arr.length; a++){   
        var partID = JSON.parse(arr[a].id)
        var uri = listID[remainder]+'/download/'+'?id='+partID
        await request.get(uri, this.onRequestDone); 
    }

    onRequestDone: async function(err, resp, body){
        await new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            if(err){
                reject(err)
            }else{
                const buf = Buffer.from(body)
                console.log("buf", buf)
                arrayPart.push(buf);
                fs.writeFileSync('message.txt', arrayPart)
                resolve(body)
            }
        });    
    }
 }
```

my onRequestDone function does not behave correctly and prints buff differently.

Comment: This does not seem to be JS.

Comment: Can you add your actual as well as expected output.

Comment: 'Synchronous' is not a correct word. It's already asynchronous because of `async`. It will be sequential.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that `request.get` accepts second callback argument means that it it's callback-based and doesn't support promises. It doesn't return a promise to await. It generally doesn't make sense to provide `async` function as a callback in places where returned promise is ignored.

`request-promise` package can be used instead:

```
const request = require('request-promise');

...
const res = await request.get(uri); 
const buf = Buffer.from(res.body);
...
```